# How do I use LINQ-to-Entities to insert data into a specific table?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Question: what is the LINQ-to-Entity code to insert an order for a **specific** customer?

[image]

**Update**

Here is the a solution (see one of the submitted answers below for a much cleaner solution):

```
using (OrderDatabase ctx = new OrderDatabase())
{
  // Populate the individual tables.

  // Comment in this next line to create a new customer/order combination.
  // Customer customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Bobby", LastName = "Davro" }; 
  // Comment in this line to add an order to an existing customer.
  var customer = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Bobby").FirstOrDefault(); 

  Order order = new Order() { OrderQuantity = "2", OrderDescription = "Widgets" }; 

  // Insert the individual tables correctly into the hierarchy.
  customer.Orders.Add(order);

  // Add the complete object into the entity.
  ctx.Customers.AddObject(customer);

  // Insert into the database.
  ctx.SaveChanges();                        
}
```

Comment: Of course, I could probably use ADO.NET to do the job - but I don't want to "pollute" my model by dealing with primary/foreign keys. Notice that the code above doesn't have primary/foreign keys - LINQ to Entities handles this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't far off. Just change your second line to read as follows:

```
Customer customer = ctx.Customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FirstName == "Bobby");
if (customer != null)
{
    //...
```

Just replace the `c.FirstName == "Bobby"` with something that can strongly identify the customer you're looking for (e.g. `c.Id == customerID` if you already know what the ID is).

Comment: Brilliant, this works nicely. I had to award the answer to you as you answered correctly first. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Notice that Order has a Customer property.  You don't have to add the Order to the Customer -- you can do it the other way around.  So, instead of creating a new Customer, get the Customer using Linq, then add it to your new Order.

```
using (OrderDatabase ctx = new OrderDatabase())
{
    ctx.AddOrder(new Order()
    {
        OrderQuantity = 2,
        OrderDescription = "Widgets",
        Customer = ctx.Customers.First<Customer>(c => c.CustomerId == yourId)
    });
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Note that you can replace the condition to select the Customer with any other relevant condition; you don't need yourId to have the CustomerId if you want to search on other criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what the problem is, exactly.

```
var mycustomer = context.Customers.Where(x => x.id == 100).FirstOrDefault();
if(mycustomer != null)
{
  mycustomer.Orders.Add(myorder); 
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

L2E does not support set-based operations currently (update without select). See [Use linq to generate direct update without select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445033/use-linq-to-generate-direct-update-without-select)

Comment: I don't think he's asking for an update without select. He mentions a LINQ query to retrieve the correct customer first.